# convert a number to 100 percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery

well, i'm trying to write my own audio player, already i got duration time and current time, now i want to show current duration in percentage with a div width. i think no need to put all my player codes here because its just a simple question. let me explain like this, so consider if:

> **duration:** 30

I want to show 30 in 100 percentage, for example if duration is **30** it show div width 100% if **15** it show 50%, like this:

```css
#duration {
height: 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="duration" style="width:100%">100%</div>
```

> **duration:** 15 (half)

```css
#duration {
height: 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="duration" style="width:50%">50%</div>
```

so this is my question code:

```js
var current = $('#current').text(); //it return 15
var duration = $('#duration').text(); //it return 30

var currPrec = current / 100; // it return 0.15%
var durPrec = duration / 100; // it return 0.03%;

$('#length').text(currPrec + "%").animate({
width: currPrec
});
```

```css
#length {
width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
currently: <a id="current">15</a>
<br/>
duration: <a id="duration">30</a>

<div id="length">0%</div>
```

but i want to show 15 as 50% and 20 as 75% and 30 as 100% but i have no idea!

Comment: Divide the current by the maximum, then multiply by 100 to get the percentage.

Comment: This is elementary school math.

Comment: (current/duration)*100

Comment: 100/(duration/currently)

Comment: @Barmar i forgot all, i always hate math! interesting! if you ask about elementary school question you get down vote! funny! here is not school guys!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there must be hundreds of math websites that explain how to do percentages.

Comment: @Barmar you right, but the problem is, i didn't know what should i search! to find this solution! anyway, hello to down voters! no problem!

Comment: Google "tutorial percentage"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `100 * (current/duration);`

```js
var current = $('#current').text(); //it return 15
var duration = $('#duration').text(); //it return 30

var currPrec = 100 * (current/duration); // it return 50%
var durPrec = duration / 100; // it return 0.03%;


$('#length').text(currPrec + "%").animate({
width: currPrec
});
```

```css
#length {
width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
currently: <a id="current">15</a>
<br/>
duration: <a id="duration">30</a>

<div id="length">0%</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var current = $('#current').text(); //it return 15
var duration = $('#duration').text(); //it return 30

var currPrec = parseInt(current)*100.0/parseInt(duration);
$('#length').text(currPrec + "%").animate({
width: currPrec
});
```

```css
#length {
width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
currently: <a id="current">15</a>
<br/>
duration: <a id="duration">30</a>

<div id="length">0%</div>
```

Comment: Both the values  accessed are in string

Comment: when you use math operators other than `+` javascript does the converion itself